# How do I add migration with multiple references to the same model in one table? Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

How do I create a migration with two fields that reference the same table? I have tables A, and image. A.image1_id will reference image, and A.image2_id will reference image also. There are only 2 images, not many. If I use

```
class AddFields < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
    change_table(:ticket) do |t|
        t.references :image1_id
        t.references :image2_id
    end
  end
end
```

I don't think that will work because it will add another _id to the end and probably won't know to use the 'image' model. I also thought about

```
change_table(:ticket) do |t|
    t.references :image
```

But then how do I add two of those? I also thought about adding

```
create_table :images do |t|
  t.belongs_to :ticket
  t.string :file
```

But I only want 2, not many, and this doesn't appear to allow getting to the image from the ticket, like `ticket.image1` or `ticket.image2`.

According to this documentation http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_table which is all I could find, t.references doesn't appear to take any arguments either.

```
change_table(:suppliers) do |t|
  t.references :company
end
```

Comment: I think now I would just create one relation and have a `before_save` filter or `validate :my_validation` to limit the relation to 2 records.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can do this simply with the `add_column` method in your migrations and set up the proper associations in your classes:

```
class AddFields < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :tickets, :image_1_id, :integer
    add_column :tickets, :image_2_id, :integer
  end
end

class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :image_1, :class_name => "Image"
  belongs_to :image_2, :class_name => "Image"
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :primary_tickets, :class_name => "Ticket", :foreign_key => "image_1_id"
  has_many :secondary_tickets, :class_name => "Ticket", :foreign_key => "image_2_id"
end
```

This blog post, [Creating Multiple Associations with the Same Table](http://www.spacevatican.org/2008/5/6/creating-multiple-associations-with-the-same-table/),  goes into more detail.

Comment: Right, `t.references :x` is just shorthand for `t.column :x_id, :integer` or `t.integer :x_id`.

Comment: So I don't need t.references to be able to use `ticket.image1` ?

Comment: Like  @muistooshort said, it's a convenience method. Yours is a special case where it's probably better to use a different helper method.

Comment: Wow `belongs_to` and `has_one` is confusing. It sounds backwards. The ticket 'references' the image, and the image 'belongs to' the ticket.

Comment: `t.references` also adds the `index: true` argument to the `add_column` method, which adds an index

Comment: @sixty4bit would adding the index in this case of having two fks be a good thing or a potentially harmful thing?

Comment: `t.references` also allows you to specify `foreign_key` (see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57322220/2871922) enabling relational integrity at the database level, so the DB want accept any old integer there, but only a primary key of the linked table.

Comment: @michaelsking1993 adding the index is definitely a good thing. Every FK should be indexed to avoid making table joins painfully slow. It wont confuse the database to have two indexed foreign keys to the same table.

Answer (score 29):

In Rails 5.1 or greater you can do it like this:

### Migration

```
class AddFields < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
    change_table(:tickets) do |t|
        t.references :image1, foreign_key: { to_table: 'images' }
        t.references :image2, foreign_key: { to_table: 'images' }
    end
  end
end
```

This will create the fields `image1_id`, and `image2_id` and make the database level references to the `images` table

### Models

as in [rossta's asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14868254/2871922)

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :image1, class_name: "Image"
  belongs_to :image2, class_name: "Image"
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :primary_tickets, class_name: "Ticket", foreign_key: "image1_id"
  has_many :secondary_tickets, class_name: "Ticket", foreign_key: "image2_id"
end
```

### FactoryBot

If you uses FactoryBot then your factory might look something like this:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :ticket do
    association :image1, factory: :image
    association :image2, factory: :image
  end
end
```