# Rails reference 2 columns from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I already saw this but I'm not sure how to apply it my particular situation [How do I add migration with multiple references to the same model in one table? Ruby/Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867981/how-do-i-add-migration-with-multiple-references-to-the-same-model-in-one-table)

I'm trying to find a way to have a model called `ChildOrganization` reference 2 columns from another model called `Organization` in a one-to-many relationship in a Rails 4.2 web app.

For example, org1 and org2 are both listed in the Organization model and have columns such as name, address, etc... but in the ChildOrganization model org1_id and org2_id should be listed under 'parent' and 'child' columns to make a parent\child pair.  The goal is to have a ChildOrganization model that lists pairs of two's from the Organization model.

the ChildOrganization has a reference column called `organization_id` that links to the Organization table and another column that just takes an integer called `child_organization_id`

in the Organization model (the below is wrong)

```
has_many :child_organizations, class_name: "ChildOrganization", foreign_key: "organization_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :child_organizations, class_name: "ChildOrganization", foreign_key: "child_organization_id", dependent: :destroy
```

in the ChildOrganization model

```
belongs_to :organization
```

**UPDATE**

Here's what worked.  In the `organization` model I have the below.  The associations can be called anything, they are not the names of models\tables.  You specify the model by using `class_name`

```
  # child_organization_parents/children associations map to foreign keys in the ChildOrganization table
  has_many :child_organization_parents, class_name: "ChildOrganization", foreign_key: "parent_org_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :child_organization_children, class_name: "ChildOrganization", foreign_key: "child_org_id", dependent: :destroy
```

in the `ChildOrganization` model

```
  belongs_to :organization
```

the migration looks like this, I added a check for null and also an index

```
create_table :child_organizations do |t|
  t.integer :parent_org_id, null: false, index: true
  t.integer :child_org_id, null: false, index: true

  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

here's the command I used to create the model that will hold the 2 foreign keys, remember to add the null:false and index:true to the migration file before running it.

```
rails g model ChildOrganization parent_org_id:integer child_org_id:integer --no-assets --no-test-framework
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This first argument after the `has_many` needs to be different.

Something like this:

```rb
has_many :child_organization_organizations, class_name: "ChildOrganization", foreign_key: "organization_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :child_organization_child_organizations, class_name: "ChildOrganization", foreign_key: "child_organization_id", dependent: :destroy
```